# Why does node.js path.resolve the empty string to the current working directory?

Tags: node.js

According to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to), node.js's `path.resolve` function converts the passed argument to an absolute path. However, when I pass it the non-existent file `''`, it returns the current working directory:

```
~$ node -v
v0.8.14
~$ node
> require('path').resolve('')
'/Users/perimosocordiae'
> require('fs').statSync('')
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory ''
```

Is this intended behavior? Are there any other cases in which a "resolved" path will exist when the input path doesn't, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other parts of the documentation say:

> If after using all `from` paths still no absolute path is found, the current working directory is used as well.

and

> the different paths don't need to exist and may also be files.

`path.resolve` can be thought of, as the docs, say, as a series of `cd` commands--e.g., what would happen if I started at `from` (or `process.cwd()` if no `from`  is specified, as in your example) and manipulated that path with the string in `to`.